# Crear JSON a partir de ejemplo C#

Tags: c#, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON que me da un proveedor:

```
{
    "maindata" : [
        {
            "resolucion" : "00000-REST-IN-00000-0000",
            "resInicio" : "1",
            "resFin" : "1000000",
            "resFecha" : "31/01/2017",
            "nit" : "0614-090588-103-8",
            "nrc" : "1227-3",
            "fechaEnvio" : "04/12/2020 18:20:10",
            "fechaEmision" : "04/12/2020",
            "terminal" : "131",
            "numFactura" : "150",
            "correlativoInterno" : "151",
            "numeroTransaccion" : "455477",
            "codigoUsuario" : "456",
            "nombreUsuario" : "Nombre Usuario",
            "correoUsuario" : "usuario@dominio.com",
            "contactos" : [
                {
                    "email" : "correo1@dominio.com",
                    "telefono": "00001111"
                },
                {
                    "email" : "correo2@dominio.com",
                    "telefono": "00002222"
                }
            ],
            "detalle" : [
                {
                    "cantidad" : 1,
                    "descripcion" : "Chocolate Blanco",
                    "precioUnitario" : 1.50,
                    "ventasNoSujetas" : 0,
                    "ventasExentas" : 0,
                    "ventasGravadas" : 1.50,
                    "desc" : "(5.00%) 1.26",
                    "fecha" : "01/10/2020",
                    "delAl" : "Del 1 - al 100",
                    "exportaciones" : 0.0,
                    "unidadMedida" : [
                        {
                            "serie" : "(ICC 895030410280908796)"
                        },
                        {
                            "serie" : "(#REF 37350200)"
                        },
                        {
                            "serie" : "(#REF ICC 8950304102809087963)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "cantidad" : 10,
                    "descripcion" : "Camisa Sport1",
                    "precioUnitario" : 8.75,
                    "ventasNoSujetas" : 0,
                    "ventasExentas" : 0,
                    "ventasGravadas" : 87.50,
                    "desc" : "(15.00%) 1.26",
                    "fecha" : "02/10/2020", 
                    "delAl" : "Del 100 - al 101", 
                    "exportaciones" : 0.0, 
                    "unidadMedida" :  [
                        {
                            "serie" : "77567896"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Usando la pagina de https://quicktype.io/csharp me forma el mapa asi:

```
namespace JSON
{
    public partial class CamposJSON
    {
        [JsonProperty("maindata")]
        public Maindatum[] Maindata { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Maindatum
    {
        [JsonProperty("resolucion")]
        public string Resolucion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("resInicio")]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long ResInicio { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("resFin")]
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public long ResFin { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("resFecha")]
        public string ResFecha { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nit")]
        public string Nit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nrc")]
        public string Nrc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fechaEnvio")]
        public string FechaEnvio { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fechaEmision")]
        public string FechaEmision { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Contacto
    {
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("telefono")]
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Detalle
    {
        [JsonProperty("cantidad")]
        public long Cantidad { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("descripcion")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("precioUnitario")]
        public double PrecioUnitario { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ventasNoSujetas")]
        public long VentasNoSujetas { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ventasExentas")]
        public long VentasExentas { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ventasGravadas")]
        public double VentasGravadas { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("desc")]
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fecha")]
        public string Fecha { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("delAl")]
        public string DelAl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("exportaciones")]
        public long Exportaciones { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("unidadMedida")]
        public UnidadMedida[] UnidadMedida { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UnidadMedida
    {
        [JsonProperty("serie")]
        public string Serie { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi problema es el siguiente: si trato de llamar el CamposJSON

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para "obtener" el json, me da NULL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si trato de obtener el Maindatum:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando esta linea, solo me obtiene los datos Main pero me omite el contacto y detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los que omite al llamar el Main

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, como hago para poder formar el JSON tal como el ejemplo de arriba? Gracias.

**EDICION**

Cambie un poco el mapa del JSON y me queda la parte de Detalle asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui en detalle se va a guardar cada una de las lineas del pedido, por ejemplo, si un pedido tiene 3 lineas (manzana con 3 unidades, pera con 4 unidades y sandia con 10 unidades), obviamente el campo unidad me va a guardar en cada campo del array [3,4,10]

Estoy asignandoselo de esta forma:

```
//DETALLE
DataTable DetalleFactura = _metodo.CantidadLineasDetalle(); //leo cuantas lineas tiene el detalle
        
//se itera en la datatable con en el fin de recorrer las N lineas
foreach (DataRow rowDeta in DetalleFactura.Rows)
{
  //se obtiene la cantidad y se asigna a la cantidad
  _olsDetalle.cantidad = _metodo.cantidad(row["xxxx"].toString());
}
```

Cuando regenero el proceso y contruyo el JSON asi:

```
var json2 = _olsMain;
var jsonBuild = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json2);
```

me devuelve lo siguiente en detalle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a tu clase Maindatum le estan faltando un monton de propiedades, por ejemplo Contactos que te sale nulo, esa clase hay que arreglar.  Si tengo tiempo te posteo una respuesta, xq es un poco trabajoso. pero con ese tip tendria que funcionarte

Comment: En lugar de usar una herramienta externa, prueba a usar la propia de Visual Studio. Copia el ejemplo de json, y en visual studio ve a Editar/Pegado Especial/Pegar JSON como clases. Por otro lado, no indicas como estas deserializando el JSON. Usas Newtonsoft?

Comment: @CarlosMarceloBuffaOrtíz no voy a poner todos por que son muchos y recorte para dar una idea. Voy a poster un poco mas

Comment: @Pikoh agregue un poco mas sobre como genero el JSON y como me esta dando la salida. Gracias.